# Explain: eval `dircolors /path/to/dircolorsdb`

Tags: 13.10, gnome-terminal, colors

Would someone be able to explain to me what this line does.

I understand that `eval` creates a command by concatenating arguments. I also understand that the the text will execute because they are inside of backticks.

I am trying to get the solarized colors in my Ubuntu 13.10 gnome-terminal. I know how to do it but I really want to understand what is going on.

I am getting the colors from this [git repository](https://github.com/huyz/dircolors-solarized)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple. `dircolors` set colour for `ls`. In the [above mentioned link](https://github.com/huyz/dircolors-solarized) there are few predefined colour scheme for `ls`.

when you run the following command in terminal

```
eval `dircolors /path/to/dircolorsdb`
```

The stored database is loaded and `ls` output colors changes accordingly. If you close the existing terminal it will not be available anymore. To make the change permanent.

> - Create a file `~/.dir_colors`
> - Copy the color database file (that you want to apply) in it.
> - Add the following command at the end of `~/.bashrc`.

```
eval `dircolors ~/.dir_colors`
```

> - Source `~/.bashrc` using the command in terminal

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

It will activate the theme for all future shell sessions.

**Note:**  There are some additional instructions for 256-color Solarized Themes. Go through the Readme before you go for it.

Comment: (8/2023) Do not use underscores anymore. To create your own database (under Debian/Ubuntu at least), I did `dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors`. Then edit `~/.dircolors` to your liking. For me it was to update the 'multihardlink/mh' entry since they appear as regular files anymore. See `/etc/skel/.bashrc` for current default eval sequence under bash. The pertinent line (no underscore in filename): `test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"`.